# Is there a way to keep linked stylesheets localized to single components?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a component that relies on external stylesheets. I'm bringing the stylesheet into the component like this:

**Child component**

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        ...my code here...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But what's happening is this is forcing those styles onto the parent component as well.

**Parent Component**

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...code here...
        <Child />
        ... more code here...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is anyone aware of a way that I can keep that stylesheet link localized to just that child component so the styles aren't applied to the parent component as well?

**Edit 2**

Currently trying the shadow dom route, trying to pass down some children. Getting an error after the initial render saying Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children'). It does render the this.props.children initially...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.innerHTML = `
      ${this.props.children}
    `;
  }
};

export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <script>
          {!customElements.get("my-component") && customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent)}
        </script>
        <my-component>
          <h1>Hello from shadow</h1>
        </my-component>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A `<link/>` element will apply to the entire html document. If you want the stylesheet to only apply to the child element, then it must have an isolated browsing context. You can do that by using an iframe. This can be useful in some use cases - like a content managment system page preview - but it's a quite niche use case.

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can try `CSS Modules`. Add `:local(.className)` to the class you want to use in your code which is in the `font-awesome-min.css` file. Then import the `styles` to your component. For example `import styles from './font-awesome-min.css'` then use the module in your code. The styles will only apply to specific element and won't affect other elements in the document. So let's say you have a class called `.usericon` in your `css` you do this in the `css` file.

```
CSS

:local(.usericon){
    fill: red;
}

React Code

import styles from './font-awesome-min.css'

export default function Profile(){
    return (
        <i className={styles.usericon}>User Icon</i>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I went ahead and downloaded the sheets I'm linking to and it looks like these styles are now applied to the entire project (instead of just the parent). Is there a way to localize imports like that so react doesn't apply them to the entire project?

Comment: import the css file into the specific component that requires it and not `App.js` or `index.js`. For example if you want to use the styles in your `Child.js` file then import the styles in that file only.

Comment: Thanks - that’s actually what I’m doing. Importing everything in the child, but it’s still being applied to the entire project for some reason

Comment: Okay, check the edits I just made up top. Let me know what you think

Comment: Please check I have updated the answer to use css modules. You can create separate css files for each component and import them to the compoment as modules instead.

Answer (score 1):

One way to truly isolate your CSS is with Web Components. Web Components are a browser API that allows defining custom elements with their own "shadow DOM". If a style is defined inside the shadow DOM, it is truly sandboxed with no styles going in or out. You can use whatever selectors you like:

```js
class FancyBox extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        .fancy-box {
          border: solid 3px darkblue;
          background: dodgerblue;
          padding: 10px;
          color: white;
          font: 16px sans-serif;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="fancy-box">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('fancy-box', FancyBox);
```

```css
.fancy-box {
  border: dashed 3px darkred !important;
  background: crimson !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
  color: white !important;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<fancy-box>Safe in my shadow DOM</fancy-box>       
<div class="fancy-box">I am affected by outside stylesheets</div>
```

Note the use of `<slot></slot>`. This is a placeholder for child elements of the component.

If I wanted to use this custom element from React, it needs to be defined separately so it only runs once.

```js
class FancyBox extends HTMLElement { /*...*/ };
customElements.define('fancy-box', FancyBox);

class ReactFancyBox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { value: 'hello world!' }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <fancy-box>
           <strong>{this.state.value}</strong>
        </fancy-box>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll give this a try. Is there anything I need to install or declare to set this up?

Comment: CSS modules just need the CSS/style loader in webpack. Web components are built in, but require a new-ish browser.  Here is a compatibility chart:
https://caniuse.com/custom-elementsv1

Comment: So can you pass props down to the shadow DOM? If you can this seems like the best answer.

Comment: Not in the sense that they are in React, where props are a declarative thing that triggers rendering when they change. But you can get and set attributes imperatively, like with DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit to the original post with where I'm at, It looks like the css is indeed local to that component, the issue now is how can I pass down some html to that shadow dom. It goes through the initial render just fine, but then gives me an error saying there aren't any props.

Comment: There are indeed no props - Web Components are a browser API that is not related to React. Edited my post to include a React example.